# How to show QDialog window over OSX Dock and OSX menu?

Tags: macos, qt

I'd like to show full screen QDialog on Mac OSX.

I tried to do that:

```
QDialog* d = new QDialog(nullptr, Qt::Window);
d->showFullScreen();
d->activateWindow();
```

It works, but this dialog creates new OSX screen:

[image: I don't want this]

I tried to do that:

```
QDialog* d = new QDialog(nullptr, Qt::SplashScreen | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
d->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
d-show();
```

It doesn't create new screen, but QDialog shows under OSX Dock and OSX menu:

[image]

How to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried to raise the window?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the normal behaviour of OS X. If you want a full screen application, without the dock and menu bar, then having a separate Desktop Screen (space) is the accepted method.

An alternative would be to maximise the size of your dialog and set the dock to hide, but you'd still be left with the menu at the top and changing the user's preference for how the dock is displayed is not a good user experience.

Comment: It's not true. How example: Joxi app: it works on Qt and shows dialog over menu and dock panels on the same screen: http://joxi.ru/V2VY6EYUejXQmv (on root screen: http://joxi.ru/DrlpKRpsElzPrP)

Comment: @fhdnsYa I don't even understand what you want. In both examples that you refer to, the menu and the dock are visible behind the application.